# Keycloak API: Getting specific message when user action is required

Tags: api, keycloak

Im calling this API Keycloak endpoint

```
/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

to obtain the user token. But the response is

```
{
"error":"invalid_grant",
"error_description":"Account is not fully set up"
}
```

and status code 400.

This response is too ambiguous. How can I get more detailed response to know that i have to redirect the user to my custom "change password" page and how can i get the user token?

Comment: any update on this.

Answer (score 1):

Login to Keycloak and check if there are any **Required User Actions** pending for the user

like (Update Password, Verify email, etc)

You can check Keycloak logs for more detail about the error

Comment: I have inserted a require action. "Update password". But i need to know that the 400 response is for "update password reason" in the API response. The are a lot of reasons that the api can throw a 400 bad request. How can I filter that the reason is "update password" Thnks!

Comment: There should not be any pending Required User Actions

Comment: @ravthiru I am facing the same problem but i have solved how to know the user has  required actions like update pass, but another problem arises after that which is to know whether its password is correct or not ? what kind of language u r using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I used workaround. Workaround is [Authentication SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi). I added new step into authentication flow like this:

```
@Override
public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
    var user = context.getUser();
    var foundUpdatePasswordRequiredAction = user.getRequiredActionsStream()
            .anyMatch(actionName -> UserModel.RequiredAction.UPDATE_PASSWORD.name().equals(actionName));

    if (foundUpdatePasswordRequiredAction) {
        context.getEvent().user(user);
        context.getEvent().error(Errors.INVALID_USER_CREDENTIALS);
        Response challengeResponse = errorResponse(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode(), "temporary_password", "Constant password is not set up");
        context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER, challengeResponse);
        return;
    }

    context.success();
}
```

It means if user has required action and the action equals "UPDATE_PASSWORD" return my error code and my error message. It works good for me.